# What href in link to title page?

Tags: html, hyperlink, href

I'm coding HTML and I'm making a link to a title page. I have two ideas:

1. relative:
   `<a href="/">`
2. absolute, for example:
   `<a href="http://www.example.com/">`

(Assuming I work on www.example.com)
Which way is better? I guess absolute way is better for SEO, because you have links to your website. But maybe the absolute way is also slower, because the browser has to ask the DNS server and load the page completely again? Thank you!

Comment: Use the secnod 1 you wont even notice the difference.

Comment: [Here's](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/11657/absolute-vs-relative-links) an interesting discussion on the topic.

Comment: As far as the browser is concerned, it uses the current site as a reference, so even if you use /thisplace.html -- If you view source in Chrome of Firefox, it will read http://example.com/thispage.html  As far as SEO, Google also sees relative links, so there really is no downside

Comment: The first example is usually referred to as **root relative** (with leading slash) and is what I usually use. Makes it more portable (for example if you have testing/staging domains that are different.)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the page is in the www.example.com domain and there is no `<base href=...>` tag, the two constructs are completely equivalent.

It is the job of the *browser* to resolve the relative URL “/” to the absolute URL “http://www.example.com”. Search engine indexing robots do the same. All caching is based on the absolute URLs, so no difference there either.

There is the practical difference that if the pages are moved to another server, the relative URL can be retained whereas the absolute URL would need to be changed.

To illustrate why the difference does not matter, consider a case where there is a difference: `href="/"` versus `href="/index.html"`. Even though they may lead to the same page, the resolved absolute URLs are different strings. In caching they will be treated as different, and search engines will treat them as different, even though they may find out that the contents are identical (especially if one of them is HTTP redirected to the other). But what matters is the difference between the absolute URLs, not absolute vs. relative.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion absolute is better, but that's subjective.

It won't be slower because of that, the DNS entries are cached anyway...

Answer (score 0):

As Zak said Google and other search engines see relative links so there is no downside there. There is a downside, however, with the absolute path.

For instance if you are linking to a absolute address like:

```
     `<a href="http://www.example.com/pages/page1.html">`
```

if you are going to be moving the pages folder and you had a relative address everything would still be alright but if you moved it and that was a absolute address, it would break.

Ex:       `<a href="http://www.example.com/webpages/pages/page1.html">`

The original link would be now broken, but a relative one would not. (For links inside the moved folder)